# Sharing data between aspx page and web api services

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, session, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a project that use angularjs as frontend and web api 2 as backend technology.
every thing is good but I want to use ssrs reports in my project. for doing this work I add a aspx web form to my web api project.

I can show this page in an iframe from my angularjs project.
the problem is that for security reasons I need to check current user role and based on this role I check report access of user.

How can I share the user info between web api and aspx form?
I use OWIN and CORS in project.